# Add X-Frame-Options in the nGinx Staticfile buildpack

Tags: nginx, cloud-foundry

I need to add the below X-Frame options in the nginx CF.

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
```

I am using Cloud Foundry Staticfile buildpacks.

If I edit nginx.conf directly, it is getting removed whenever I deploy my application. So it is recommended to added through Staticfile buildpack.

But I don't know the exact value for the x-frame options.

Reference: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, you do not want to edit the config file directly. Your change will disappear the next time your app is restarted, restaged, recreated, crashes or even the next time the platform moves the app due to maintenance.

If you follow the [instructions for adding custom Nginx configuration](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html#custom-location), you can put the configuration into a snippet & the Nginx configuration generated by the Staticfile buildpack will automatically read your config snippet.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much Sir.

Answer (score 0):

**Nginx.conf file Enable X-Frame-Options**

```
location ~* \.(?:html)$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  add_header Cache-Control  'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0';
  add_header X-Frame-Options 'SAMEORIGIN';
  add_header X-Frame-Options 'DENY';
  add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self';";      
  expires 0;
}
```